# How to add delimiter to each_char function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, helper

I have this Ruby function:

```
def project_total_counter
  total = Project.all.count
  spans = []
  total.to_s.each_char do |c|
    spans << content_tag(:span, c)
  end
  spans.join().html_safe
end
```

It yields something like:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>2</span>
```

How can I add a delimiter to this, so I get this:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
,
<span>5</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>2</span>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are also using the Rails framework, right?

Comment: @maerics: yes, indeed

Comment: Does that comma happen to be exactly after span 3 because it is the thousands delimiter?

Comment: Yes, it should also appear after span 6, 9, 12 and so forth.

Comment: @Tintin81 Would you please add that information to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively (assuming Rails):

```
spans = ""
number_with_delimiter(Project.all.count, :delimiter => ',').each_char do |c|
    if c == ','
        spans << c
    else
        spans << content_tag(:span, c)
    end
end
spans.html_safe
```

Or, more tersely:

```
number_with_delimiter(Project.all.count, :delimiter => ',').each_char.inject("") do |s, c|
    s << if c == ',' then c else content_tag(:span, c) end
end.html_safe
```

Comment: *If* using Rails, this is the most elegant answer.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for me because I am indeed using Rails here. Thanks!

Comment: @CDub the problem was tagged `ruby-on-rails`, and there was an expression `Project.all.count`, so I figured it was a safe bet. :)

Comment: Touche... Or threeche, @mbratch... :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it as below using [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) :

```
def project_total_counter
  total = Project.all.count
  spans  = total.to_s.chars.each_slice(3).flat_map do |ary|
    ary.map { |c| content_tag(:span, c) }.push(",")
  end
  spans[0..-2].join().html_safe
end
```

Comment: This will produce "123,45," for "12345"

Comment: I guess the `span` argument to the block should be `spans`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to reverse the string first, in order to ensure you always have three remaining digits, and not end up with something like "123,45" or "123,45,":

If you're comfortable with regex:

```
def project_total_counter
  results = []

  Project.all.count.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse.each do |char|
    results << char == "," ? "," : content_tag(:span, char)
  end

  results
end
```

I prefer @mbratch's answer, assuming you're using Rails.  The benefit of the above regex is it works in pure Ruby as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
total.to_s.each_char.map.with_index do |c, i|
  content_tag(:span, c) + (i == 2 ? ',' : '')
end.join().html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def project_total_counter
  total = Project.count
  span_groups = []
  total.to_s.each_char.in_groups_of(3) do |chars|
    span_groups << chars.map{|c| content_tag(:span, c)}.join
  end
  span_groups.join("\n,\n").html_safe
end
```

or the more terse

```
def project_total_counter
  Project.count.to_s.each_char.in_groups_of(3).map{|chars| chars.map{|c| content_tag(:span, c)}.join}.join("\n,\n").html_safe
end
```

Note that you can just say Project.count rather than Project.all.count

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Rails, make use of `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`

```
total = Project.all.count

include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
number_with_delimiter(total, delimiter: ",").each_char.map { |c|
  content_tag(:span, c)
}.join.html_safe
```